# Add very nice lambda in empheq package or package-less

Tags: math-operators, letters, empheq

My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{empheq}

%\usepackage{mathptmx}

\begin{document}
\begin{empheq}{align}
\lambda\\
R_{eş}\\
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

is output

[image]

But that I can add {mathptmx} package is output

[image]

some Turkish letters is deleting. I want add very **NICE LAMBDA**, is it possible?

Note: Turkish {R_eş} = English {R_eq}

Comment: How about using `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`?

Comment: OK, I am checking.

Comment: **This NFSS system isn't set up properly.** I will set up NFSS.

Comment: You are using miktex then :) This seems to be the problem with it.

Comment: Dear Harish Kumar, I am using **LaTeXila 2.4.1** and **TeXstudio 2.8.4** in **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**. Is it good? Your recommend?

Comment: Not MiKTeX then, but TeX Live? No matter what, I get `command \c invalid in math mode`. You can write @HarishKumar to 'ping' somebody.

Comment: Ubuntu's packages are not very current, especially if you are using the versions from LTS, I imagine. Which version of TeX Live do you have? (Look at the console output from running `pdflatex` or whatever. The version information appears at the beginning of the run.) I'm guessing probably 2012. I don't know but it maybe that updated packages have fixed a bug causing this. Although if it is complaining about NFSS, that seems a bit odd. (But it could just me another singularly unhelpful error message.)

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the suffix to R is textual (and not mathematical) you should use the package amsmath and the command \text in

```
 R_{\text{eş}}
```

This will take care of two things: the letters "e" and "ş" are both roman (upright) and the encoding will work, too.

Comment: Use `\textnormal`, if you want to ensure the font is upright in any context.